# Как интегрировать приложение написанное на Java с Windows Server?

Tags: java, windows, сервер, windows-server

Ребята, такой вопрос, пока для меня совсем черный ящик. Это из реально существующей задачи, нужно сделать рабочее место (десктопное или веб интерфейс, не важно)) , авторизация и роли должны браться из Windows Server, базовый язык JAVA, есть БД MS Server и я не могу понять архитектуру, как все это будет интегрировано, как Winodws Server будет обмениваться с приложением, как будет происходить защита информации, где можно почерпнуть информацию, может на GitHub есть похожий пример? или минимальный стек, который должен использовать, и от этого уже буду отталкиваться) Заранее спасибо)

Comment: мне кажется винда не даст юзеров и роли.

Comment: @Tsyklop с помощью JNDI можно из AD получить и пользователей, и их членство в группах, а с помощью JAAS можно использовать доменные службы авторизации и аутентификации.